# Value of field when field doesn't exist

Tags: apex, custom-field, dynamic-apex

I am trying to access the value of a field on a custom object dynamically.
e.g. customObject__c currently doesn't have customField1__c on it. It will be created in the future. Is there a way that I can use this name and value (I know the name of the field but not value. Value will be given in the future when it will be created) in the apex code?

```
for(customObject__c co:lstCustomobjects){
   String str;
   str = co.customField1__c; //currently if I try this, I get error variable doesn't exists - customField1__c which is understandable
   system.debug(str); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic Apex:

```
for(CustomObject__c co: lstCustomobjects) {
  String str = (String)co.get('customField1__c');
  // etc
}
```

Where `sObject.get(String)` is a method that accepts a field name, and returns an `Object`. This is then cast using `(String)` so that it can be assigned to a `String` variable.

However, note that this would throw an exception if the field does not exist, so a full solution would be to check for the field first:

```
if(sObjectType.CustomObject__c.fields.getMap().get('customField1__c') != null) {
  for(CustomObject__c co: lstCustomobjects) {
    String str = (String)co.get('customField1__c');
    // etc
  }
}
```